# Anaconda is saying it is in offline mode but PC is connected

Tags: anaconda

Anaconda will not install packages, because it is in offline mode... but actually it is online.
Any ideas?
PC
WiFi
Windows 10
Anaconda 64 bit version Python 3.7

Comment: So the reason this matters to me is for installing packages. As it happens... I can still do this if I use the console, just not with Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: And the only solution was to attach an Ethernet cable. Now it’s sorted, but it must be a bug in that installation because Anaconda works fine on my other WiFi pc and iMac.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the preferences for Anaconda Navigator and uncheck the [Offline Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CuP1.png) this will disable the Offline mode